# Variable functions with namespaces in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm wondering if there is a way to call variable functions with namespaces. Basically I'm trying to parse tags and send them to template functions so they can render html`

Here's an Example: (I'm using PHP 5.3)

```
 // Main php file
require_once 'template.php';
foreach (array("javascript","script","css") as $tag) {
    echo template\$tag();
}

 // template.php
 namespace template;

 function javascript() { return "Hello from javascript"; }
 function css() { return "Hello from css"; }
 function script() { return "Hello from script"; }
```

I keep getting 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING in ... on line 76

Thanks! Matt

Comment: You're using the [*Variable functions*](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) wrong, it needs to be a variable, not a string and variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can, but unfortunately, you need to use [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/call-user-func) to achieve this:

```
require_once 'template.php';
foreach (array("javascript","script","css") as $tag) {
    echo call_user_func('template\\'.$tag);
}
```

Namespaces in PHP are fairly new. I'm sure that in the future, they will fix it so we won't require [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/call-user-func) anymore.

Comment: Needed a parameter. Here's how to do that.

echo call_user_func('template\\'.$tag, $params);

Answer (score 7):

This will also work, no need for `call_user_func`, just use the [*Variable functions*<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) feature:

```
require_once 'template.php';

$ns = 'template';
foreach (array('javascript', 'script', 'css') as $tag) {
    $ns_func = $ns . '\\' . $tag;
    echo $ns_func();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
 // Main php file
require_once 'template.php';
foreach (array("javascript","script","css") as $tag) {
    call_user_func("template\\$tag"); // As of PHP 5.3.0
}

 // template.php
 namespace template;

 function javascript() { return "Hello from javascript"; }
 function css() { return "Hello from css"; }
 function script() { return "Hello from script"; }
```

you have some info [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

Comment: `::`? Really... Someone either didn't do their homework or simply has no understanding of the difference between a namespace and a static member of a class.

Comment: Thanks! Only slightly off though! I appreciate the help though.

Comment: @Andrew you were right. I messed it up when is pasted the code. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$p = 'login';
namespace App\login; 
$test2 = '\App\\'.$p.'\\MyClass';

$test = new $test2;
```