# Calling a static method when the class is a variable with namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces

I have the following code that I'm using in a small frame work I've put together. My framework didn't originally use Namespaces, but since two class names collide in this project I figured it would be a good time to try this out. The following error is thrown when the script is executed:

```
[Wed May 02 15:04:33 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING in /home/marco/Projects/stackgaming.com/app/server.php on line 17
```

Here is the following code snippets relevant to the error:

app/server.php

```
if( !defined('IN_APP') ) { die('THESE ARE NOT THE DROIDS YOU ARE LOOKING FOR'); }

require_once('model/Server.php');

\Model\Server::$save_path = APPLICATION_ROOT . 'servers';

class Server extends App
{
    public static function init($server_id)
    {
        $server_data = \Model\Server::get($server_id);
        $game = $server_data['interface'];
        require_once('model/' . $game . '.php');

        $query_data = \Model\$game::query($server_data['host'], $server_data['query_port']);

        var_dump($server_data);
        var_dump($query_data);

        //static::$View->display('user_main.tpl');
    }
}
```

This is the model/Minecraft.php file, which is what `$game` resolves to.

```
<?php

namespace Model;

class MinecraftException extends \Exception
{
    // Exception thrown by Minecraft classes
}

class Minecraft
{
    public static function query( $host, $port = 25565, $timeout = 3 )
    {
        $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

        socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array('sec' => $timeout, 'usec' => 0));

        if( $socket === false || @socket_connect($socket, $host, (int)$port) === false )
        {
            return false;
        }

        socket_send($socket, "\xFE", 1, 0);
        $len = socket_recv($socket, $data, 256, 0);
        socket_close($socket);

        if( $len < 4 || $data[ 0 ] != "\xFF" )
        {
            return false;
        }

        $data = substr($data, 3);
        $data = iconv('UTF-16BE', 'UTF-8', $data);
        $data = explode("\xA7", $data);

        return array
        (
            'hostname'   => substr($data[0], 0, -1),
            'total_players'    => isset($data[1]) ? intval($data[1]) : 0,
            'max_players' => isset($data[2]) ? intval($data[2]) : 0
        );
    }
}
```

If I remove the namespace from Minecraft class it works fine, but if I'm going to use namespaces shouldn't I go all the way?

Comment: `s/minecraft/game-that-is-socially-more-acceptable/g`

Comment: This question has been asked before IIRC, but probably harder to locate on this site. Keep searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this question much sooner than I found a resolution to it. For everyone's benefit, here is a helpful link to resolving the issue at hand: [Variable functions with namespaces in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250297/variable-functions-with-namespaces-in-php)

Comment: So this question is a dupe, as you have no answer other than "see this other question as it answers yours here".